# 2D dynamic array in c - accessing allocated variable

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, syntax

I'm struggling (again..) with a project in C coding.

Please help me to understand how to access a variable that was dynamically allocated, through 2D array that was also dynamically allocated.
Every attempt ends up with failure, and I can't find the right syntax...

The attempt : putting a string in the family_name pointer in the new Family allocated into **list.

```
scanf(" %s",&lod->list[0]->family_name);
```

The program:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
//Libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Consts, globals, structs 

#define MAX 10000

typedef struct person
{
    char *name;
    int gender;         //1-female, 0-male
} Person;

typedef struct family
{
    char *family_name;
    Person *mother, *father;    // parents' names
    Person **children_list; // list of the children in this family
    unsigned child_list_size;   // size of child_list array
    unsigned current_listChild_size;
} Family;

typedef struct listFamilys
{
    Family **list;
    unsigned current_listFamily_size;   // current size of family
}
ListFamilys;

//main
void main()
{
    ListFamilys *lod = (ListFamilys*) malloc(sizeof(ListFamilys));
        if(! lod) exit(0);
        lod->current_listFamily_size =0;
    lod->list = (Family**)malloc(sizeof(Family*));
    if (!lod->list) exit(0);
    printf("Enter family name: ");
    **scanf(" %s",&lod->list[0]->family_name);**
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Can't compile the code without the `TownInit` function.

Comment: The function does dynamic allocation of ListFamilys and puts 0 in current_listFamily_size.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to actually update the code in your question to include it.

Comment: Done. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is simply a type error combined with insufficient allocation. In order for this to work you need to allocate space for some Family pointers (which you are doing, though only 1), and then an actual Family element (which you are not doing) and then allocate space for the name (which you are not doing). Basically, the code should be

```
lod->list = (Family**) malloc(sizeof(Family*));
lod->list[0] = (Family*) malloc(sizeof(Family));
lod->list[0]->family_name = (char*) calloc(11, 1);
```

where you are only doing the first line of that. My usage of `calloc` here is somewhat arbitrary, as is the 10 char limit. You can modify as is appropriate.

However, while this is the simplest way to get a single element up and running, this approach collapses at the large scale because of how many allocations you have to do, and deallocating memory becomes a nightmare due to how many separate allocations are made using this approach. Therefore, it is better to allocate say 4kb of space for names to a separate pointer, and then point the name field of persons and families to the relevant name rather than a separate allocation for each of their names. So on with the rest of it. Essentially, try to extract allocations rather than tunnel down with them field after field like the code above does.

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to put a string in "family_name" after creating a new family object? : lod->list[0]->family_name = "string" ;

Comment: Not necessarily. You can make a string with an array: `char s[] = "string"` and then point it to that `(...)family_name = string` but then that will only be valid as long as `s` is alive. If that's in `main`, then it's forever but you can never expand the name further than that.

Comment: Also, if the answer solved your problem, please rate it as such.